# Consolidate Text Data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, charts

I have an Excel document containing exam results. The results are in one column and appear as `Pass` or `Fail`.

I want to know percent of candidates who passed.

Comment: start learning pivot tables, great resource for quick calculations.

Comment: I suppose we can say with confidence that the subject of the exam was not maths

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following scenario:

[image]

To calculate the percentage of Pass you need to divide the number of Pass values by the total number of values.

The formula in F2 is

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,D2)/(COUNTA(B:B)-1)
```

In words: count how many items in column B equal the text in D2. Divide that by the total number of items in column B, but subtract 1 for the label row.

Copy down to F3 to get the percentage of Fails. In column E you see a simple count with the Counta() function.

If you want to show the data in a chart, this is one of the few cases where a pie chart makes sense. Select D1 to E3 and insert a pie chart. You can add data labels that will show the percentage. You don't need to calculate the percentage in the worksheet in order for a pie chart to show them.